# Input field validation before submitting form in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angular, typescript

My aim is to ensure that the user enters valid data (No numbers) and input field should not be empty before the form is submitted. Help!!!

The ts file code as follows:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { Component, NgModule, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Environments } from './Environment-class';
import { FormBuilder, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'addenvironment-form',
templateUrl: './add-environment-form.component.html'
  })
 export class AddEnvironmentComponent {

@Output() EnvironementCreated = new EventEmitter<Environments>();
createNewEnv(EnvironmentNames: string) {
    this.EnvironementCreated.emit(new Environments(EnvironmentNames));
}
```

}

And the HTML file

```
<br />
<div class="card">
<h4 class="card-header">Add a New Environment</h4>
<div class="card-body mx-auto  ">
    <form class="form-inline ">
        <div class="form-group ">

            <h5 class="form-control-static">Enter New Name: </h5>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mx-lg-3 text-center">
            <label for="inputPassword2" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control " id="inputPassword4" placeholder=" Name " #EnvironmentNames>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="createNewEnv(EnvironmentNames.value)">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `required` tag to input filed so it has to be filled in.
Additionally you can add `minlength`.
To make it letters only you can use `pattern`. You can play with characters you what to allow user to input.

If you are going to use this input for password, I would suggest you to change `type` to `type="password"`

You can also `disable` button if the form is not valid.

With all this mentioned above, your form should look something like bellow:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" class="form-inline ">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <h5 class="form-control-static">Enter New Name: </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mx-lg-3 text-center">
        <label for="inputPassword2" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control " id="inputPassword4" 
         placeholder=" Name " #EnvironmentNames pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" 
         minlength="8" required>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
     (click)="createNewEnv(EnvironmentNames.value)"
     [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit
    </button>
</form>
```